# Geometric progression

Tags: sequences-and-series

In a G.P. the sum of the first and last terms is equal to 66. the product of the second and second last term is 128. What is the first term.
Options are-
a) 64
b)64 or 2
c)2 or 32
d) none of the above
Pls explain the question with working.

Answer (score 1):

$a_1 + a_n = 66$, and $a_2 \cdot a_{n-1} = 128$. So: $ra_1\cdot \dfrac{a_n}{r} = 128$, and this gives:  $a_1 \cdot a_n = 128$. Then $a_1$ is a zero of the quadratic equation: $x^2 - 66x + 128 = 0$. Hence: $(x - 2)(x - 64) = 0$. So $x = 2$ or $x = 64$. So the answer is b)

Comment: That was real useful. Thanks and keep answering!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically :

$U_0 + U_n = 66$

$U_1\cdot U_{n-1} = 128$

Which means :

$U_0(1+q^n)=66$ (1)

$U_0^2 \cdot q^n = 128$ (2)

We eliminate the $q^n$ which is not important here, by multiplying the first equation by $U_0$ and substracting (2) with (1)

We get :

$$U_0^2 - 66U_0 + 128 = 0$$

Then you solve for $U_0$ and you obtain $U_0 = 62$ and $U_0 = 2$